# distinguish between comment and multiplication when using * sign in notepad++

Tags: comments, notepad++, multiplication

When using * sign, how can I distinguish between comment and multiplication in notepad++. Anytime I use * in an expression, notepad++ interpret it as comment sign

Comment: For this question, I use notepad++ as a text editor to write program in Stata; However, the question may apply to other uses as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stata is not recognized by default by notepad++, but you can define it, go to language menu and choose the before last option, define your language, then you can define comments and other settings.